# Passing the object Timestamp + the object ID when deleting an item inside a WebGrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, webgrid

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc view:-

```
     <div style="margin-top:17px;">
                @{
                var grid = new WebGrid(
                            canPage: true,
                            rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
                            canSort: true,
                            ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

               //code goes here
grid.Column(header: "Action", canSort: false, style: "action",
                       @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/phone/details/" + item.ID + "' id='" + item.ID + "' title='Detail'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'> </span> </a>")
                       @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/phone/edit/" + item.ID + "' id='" + item.ID + "' title='Edit'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'> </span> </a>")
                       @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/phone/delete/" + item.ID + "' id='" + item.ID + "' title='Delete'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </span> </a>")
                    </text>)

                ));
                }
```

as you can see when deleting an item inside the Grid i will be sending the ID . but i want to send the object timestamp beside the ID, so my action method looks as follow:-

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, Byte[] timestamp)
    {
        try
        {
            var phone = db.Phones.Find(id);
            phone.timestamp = timestamp;
            db.Phones.Remove(phone);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        {
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
```

so can anyone adivce of which approaches i can follow to do so ? usually when i send the timestamp i post back the whole model, but not sure if this is achievable inside the WebGrid, to post back the whole grid column to my Post delete action method ?
Thanks

Comment: You could try something like `href='/phone/delete/" + item.ID + "'?timestamp="' + Convert.ToBase64String(item.Version) + "' ...` which should generate something like `href="/phone/delete/1?timestamp=AAAAAAABX5E="`, although I am unsure exactly what your doing - your generating a link (GET method) but have shown your POST method

Comment: You might also need to ensure the `[Timestamp]` attribute is applied to the property so its correctly converted back when you post.

Comment: @StephenMuecke now i will be posting to a Post delete action method using a javascript. and i already have the timestamp added do not worry. but is there a way to post the whole grid column to my Post delete action method using ajax.beginform ??? so instead of having to worry about converting the timestamp just to post the whole grid column's object and benefit from model binding? , as i can not find a way to wrap the grid column inside a delete ajax.beginform ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebGrid, but from my understanding you can create template columns where you could include a `@HtmlEditorFor()`, but not sure that using `@Ajax.BeginForm()` is correct for a Delete action. Why not just include a button with `data-*` attributes - `<button class="delete" data-id="@item.ID" ....>` and the handle the click event to post the values `$(yourgrid).on('click', '.delete', function() { $.post(url, {id: $(this).data('id') version: $(this).data('version') }, function(data) { // delete the row? });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke my current approach is that if i can achieve any functionality with asp.net MVC ajax helpers including both Ajax.ActionLink & Ajax.BeginForm then i go with them, other wise i use jQuery. now when i use table not grid it is simple to include the table row to be wrapped inside and ajax.beginform, so when you click on the Ajax.Beginform the grid column will be submitted to the post action method, instead of having to manually pass the id + timestamp.. but i am not sure if this is achievable within the WebGrid ?

Comment: I don't know enough about webgrid to answer, but as a side note, you cant wrap a `<tr>` element in a form (it's invalid html), only a `<table>` element (or a `<form>` can go inside a `<td>` element